# Java primitive types XML text values

Tags: java, xml, primitive-types

I need to create an XML fragment and I am using Java DOM for this.

Any documentation I could find explains that one can use *Element.setTextContent()*, like so:

```
Integer someValue = 5;
Element element = myMethodCreatingTheElement();
element.setTextContent(String.valueOf(someValue));
```

My question is: is it enough to rely on *String.valueOf()* to represent the corresponding value correctly in XML?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: it works, what is your problem??

Comment: I do not know for sure this approach is safe and guarantees 100% correctness, e.g. what if the value is real and maybe there are some localization consideretion that need to be made, so my problem is that I cannot find official documentation describing the conversion of primitive values to Xml values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` to convert XML text to/from Java data types (part of JDK/JRE since Java SE 6).  This will ensure that XML specific things about the text representation are properly handled.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html

Answer (score 1):

Try for jsoup it's also good [Java DOM](http://jsoup.org/)

Answer (score 1):

> is it enough to rely on String.valueOf() to represent the corresponding value correctly in XML?

The DOM is an abstract data model for XML documents.  When you call `setTextContent()` you're setting the *value* of the element (strictly speaking you're setting the children of the element to be a single text node with the specified value).  When you write the DOM tree out as an XML document, it is the serializer's job to ensure that all the values are output in the correct *representation*.

As long as the value you're setting doesn't contain any characters that are forbidden in XML (control characters below U+0020 apart from tab, newline and carriage return, or unpaired surrogates) then you'll be fine, the serializer will perform any necessary escaping for you.

As for `String.valueOf` itself, its rules for converting primitive types to strings are laid out in detail in the JavaDoc documentation.  With the above caveat about avoiding illegal characters if you're converting a `char`, `char[]` or an `Object` that overrides `toString`, the values produced by `String.valueOf` will always be legal in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

See also [the API of java.lang.Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28%29)

Comment: Anything specific to look for there? Note that I am using String.valueOf()

Comment: Ah, my bad. In that case: No. You'll get "null" if `someValue` is null, which is not an xml integer value. If you want a type safe way of converting java types to xml "primitive" types you should use some sort of mapping.